# Android Navigation java.language.IllegalStateException fragment class was not set

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

[Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T50t7.png)

In this when I click Saved Result it shows all the saved results with date.
[The image showing saved results in `SavedResultsFragment`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY6xg.png)

[Navigation Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsglV.png)

When I click on any item it should show all the details of that clicked item in `ShowSavedResltsFragment` but instate app crashes and `IllegalStateException` is raised with fragment class was not set.

[The image showing navigation layout and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgYpG.png)

[The image showing code logic where trying to switch to `ShowResultsFragment` from `SavedResultFragment`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvM4d.png)

I'm using safe args and all but only issue is faced when I try to navigate between `SavedResultFragment` to `ShowSavedResultsFragment`. I tried to search official documentation and Stack Overflow but didn't found anything which I was facing. Official documentation gives a hint that `navHostfragment` is not implemented properly then this can trigger above exception but I'm using their official documentation but only thing I have done here is navigating to a `Fragment` through Navigation Drawer and then from that fragment trying to navigate to another fragment and this is where it breaks.

[Image showing exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDGOP.png)
Edit: NavHostFragment code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <merge>
        <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

                <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
                    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:defaultNavHost="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navVew"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
                app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />
        </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </merge>
</layout>
```

Comment: Please add the code where you have defined `NavHostFragment`.

Comment: Added the code of  ```NavHostFragement```.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration of your `ShowSavedResultsFragment` inside your nav graph doesn't have a `name` attribute attached to it.

If you look at the `SavedResultFragment` declaration, you'll notice it has a `name` attribute.

Add a `name` attribute to your `ShowSavedResultsFragment` declaration. The value of the `name` attribute should be the package name of the `ShowSavedResultsFragment` class .(dot) the name of the class. Something like `com.xxx.yyy.savedresult.ShowSavedResultsFragment`

Comment: Yes that was a culprit. You have good eyes.

Comment: @RajatNaik kindly mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

This is what is given in Fragment's `findNavController()` documentation-  `"Calling this on a Fragment that is not a [NavHostFragment] or within a [NavHostFragment] will result in an [IllegalStateException]"`. Just replace it with

```
 Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.myNavHostFragment)
                        .navigate(..)
```

Comment: I appreciate that but it didn't worked. It gives same exception with Fragrant class was not set. Edit

Comment: Is there any limitations, like I'm trying to swap fragment from another fragment through drawer layout can this be the reason for that error?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in `ShowSavedResultsFragment` due to which the exception was raised.
Still I was not able to figure out where that bug was so I deleted the fragment and associated view models and re created them and the exception was not raised again and everything worked fine. 
Edit: There was not a real bug introduced by me but I had changed class name and this type of things can raise exception because under the hood IDE does mapping and generating class names on it's own and linking them so Invalidating Caches and rebuilding the project would had helped.